# Mail Infrastructure

Tags: postfix

I want to have an infrastructure for our mail service. We had recently a problem with an mail server, because he was flagged as Spammer. The problem was that many mails goes over this server, and 30% couldn't get delivered (because a bad reputation). The thing is, we want to avoid such a problem in the future. But I don't know what is the best solution? I can imagine two solutions :

1 solution 
We could create a server which is a replica from the original server and we could simply change the DNS record in case of an outage.

2 Solution would be to have more SMTP server which are responsible for sending mails (in front of an load balancer)? If one gets flagged, the service isn't down and emails gets delivered and we have enough time to find and fix the problem.

Much Appreciated! 
Markus

Comment: if you're going to DIY, you should have 2 mailing clusters, bulk and transactional/conversation. there's a ton of info here. otherwise you can be lazy and go o365/gsuite + sendgrid/mandrill/sparkpost

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule don't send bulk mail through your main server. If you really need to do any kind of bulk mailing use a third party service so that they can take the reputation hit. They also tend to be smarter about the delivery (spreading across multiple servers, spreading over time, etc) then your average person running a single SMTP server.

Comment: that's the easy route, make it someone else's problem.

Comment: No, it is a much easier route than learning how to properly configure and manage an internet facing MTA with SPF, DMAC, RMX, and learning how to properly deliver mail and avoid upsetting everyone else's reputation filters.